# Independently updatable parts of a resource – how to ...?

Tags: rest

As far as I know, if *two parts* of a *same resource* are *independently updatable*, then they should be separately addressable resources.

Say we have an **order resource** with state such as `<name>`, `<quantity>`, `<milk>` etc.

**a)** if `<milk>` state is *updatable independently* from other parts of **order resource**, then I assume we should create a *separate resource* containing just `<milk>` state?

**b)** If my assumption in **a)** is correct, then we'd have *two resources* **R1** and **R2**, where **R2** would only contain `<milk>` state, while **R1** would contain all other state. But should **R1** also contain `<milk>` state?

**c)** I assume even if **R1** also contains `<milk>` state, *consumers* shouldn't be able to also set `<milk>` state when updating **R1**?

**d)** Assuming **R1** shouldn't contain `<milk>` state, then how do we indicate to *consumers* that **R1** and **R2** combined represent **order**?

thank you